# Spring introduction accessing original introduced class

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I am trying to use Spring framework AOP to extend some class AImpl (which implements interface A) to be able to implement also new interface B.

I am using @DeclareParents and implementing Aspect. Unfortunatelly I need to access some methods of A to be able to implement business logic within it.

Does anyone knows better solution than adding A as a parameter to interface B method ?

Does anybody used successfully Spring AOP introductions to extend class in such a way I need to ?  All the samples I have been able to find extends class A only in "static way" without need to call methods from A.

So far I have found only AopContext.currentProxy() method which I consider as very ugly hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you have only 2 ways to get access to A from B

- AopContext.currentProxy() - not so ugly but forces you to use `expose-proxy="true"`
- directly inject A in B via Spring - not so bad is both are singletons

I tried to use an around advice on a method of interface B hoping to access the original proxy that would have implemented both interfaces. But Spring replaces it by another proxy that only implements B to have a correct target.

There is effectively a third way but IMHO this one **is** really ugly : have all methods of interface B explictely take a parameter implementing A ... bof ...  :-(

Comment: The way to inject A in B via Spring is the best option in my case as my business logic can be refactored to Spring singleton classes so I will choose it. Expose-proxy="true" is the reason why I consider AopContex way as ugly - it slows down AOP. May thanks :)