# Accessing advised objects methods from a default implementation

Tags: java, spring, aop, mixins

I am trying to find out what is the usability of inter-type declarations in Spring AOP but I am stuck with one problem that makes it a bit useless.

`HelloMixin` aspect declares that advised services implement `HelloService` and provides a default implementation `HelloServiceImpl`.

```
@Aspect
public class HelloMixin {
    @DeclareParents(value = "xxx.xxx.services.*+", defaultImpl = HelloServiceImpl.class)
    static HelloService mixin;
}
```

Then I have two services:

```
@Service
public class FirstService {
    private String name = "First";
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

@Service
public class SecondService {
    private String name = "Second";
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

New interface:

```
public interface HelloService {
    public void sayHello();
}
```

Default implementation:

```
public class HelloServiceImpl implements HelloService {
    private String getName() {
        return "defaultName";
    }

    @Override
    public void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello " + getName());
    }
}
```

Execution:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("firstService")
HelloService firstService;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("secondService")
HelloService secondService;

public String hello() {

    firstService.sayHello();
    secondService.sayHello();
}
```

Result:

```
INFO: Hello defaultName
INFO: Hello defaultName
```

This concept could be really cool if I had a way to use `getName` methods from advised objects. Otherwise I do not see any sense to use it if I am not able to write any object dependent logic. Is it possible? In other words I would like to see the result:

```
INFO: Hello First
INFO: Hello Second
```

Comment: No. This code works. This is the feature that I am trying to figure out :) More about this you can find here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/aop.html
(section 7.2.5 Introductions)

Comment: Could it be a duplicate of [Spring introduction accessing original introduced class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24992232/spring-introduction-accessing-original-introduced-class) ?

Comment: actually, yes its very similar. I have not seen it before. The answer provided there is not satisfying me however it may be correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it using `@DeclareMixin` instead, that allows to use a factory method for creating the delegate.

```
@Aspect
public class HelloMixin {
    @DeclareMixin("xxx.xxx.services.*+")
    public HelloService createHelloService(Object target) {
        return new HelloServiceImpl(target);
    }
}

public class HelloServiceImpl implements HelloService {
    private Object target;

    public HelloServiceImpl(Object target) {
        this.target = target;
    }

    @Override
    public void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello " + getNameFromTarget());
    }

    private String getNameFromTarget() {
         // call to this.target.getName()....
    } 

}
```

Spring AOP don't support `@DeclareMixin` annotation, see https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11350 but I added it to JDAL 2.0 in a small independent module [jdal-aop](https://github.com/chelu/jdal/tree/master/aop), so I encourage you to try it.